# Linux Terminal ./code.py operates using Python 2.7.13 while the IDLE uses Python 3.5.3

Tags: python, linux, terminal, debian-based

Using a Debian-based Linux distro (Kali) for Python programming (note that I am very new to Linux, had it for less than 2 months). Installed Python and GitKraken the usual way with `apt-get install`.

Started happily coding using the 3.5.3 IDLE, but when I tried to use pip commands to install modules (all of this as root user), I found it was installing to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` rather than the Python 3.5.3 location (`/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages`).

When I used `pip install module`, it installed all modules to the 2.7 location. Because the Terminal used 2.7 by default (for whatever reason), using `./code.py` always ran code using Python 2.7, but I wrote the code for Python 3.5 (not the version the modules were installed for).

I saw some other answers on this website for similar problems, where you have to install new modules and change the `PYTHONPATH` variable and assign aliases, but it messed more stuff up. Now `echo $PYTHONPATH` returns nothing, and pip still installs to the Python 2.7 location.

I used `apt-get` to install python-pip3 and I use the pip3 command to install modules, but whenever I use `./code.py` (my main method to run code), it still uses Python 2.7. How can I change this?

Comment: If you have `pip3`, then try `python3 code.py` to run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the shebang at the first line of `code.py` to point to your Python 3.5 binary, e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Or if it's not linked as `python3` figure out were your Python 3.5 binary is and use that.

Comment: Originally had `#!/usr/bin/python`, had to add a 3.5 at the end. Now (with aliases for `pip` and `python`), everything runs good.

Comment: Using env as in the answer is preferable because it is more portable - the install location of env is well standardized across unix systems and linux distributions, the location of (and exact sub-version) of python is not. `/usr/bin/env python3`  is more likely to work on another system than `/usr/bin/python3.5`. Even if the other system has `python3` in the path, it could be in `/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`, and it could be `python3.6` or some other name, etc.